# how to parse data from json

Tags: android, json, httprequest

i tried to parse json data, but it kind of weird because it not show the right data but if i tried to called json on browser it has the right data.

so this is how i parse the json data

```
doAsync {
        val url = localhost.getMovie()
        val request = okhttp3.Request.Builder().url(url).build()
        val client = OkHttpClient()

        uiThread {
            client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback, okhttp3.Callback {
                override fun onResponse(call: okhttp3.Call?, response: okhttp3.Response?) {
                    val body = response?.body()?.string()
                    println(body)
                    uiThread {
                        val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
                        val movieFeed = gson.fromJson(body, Movie2Response::class.java)

                        Log.v("body", ""+body)
                        Log.v("feed", ""+movieFeed.data)

                        uiThread {
                        }
                    }
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: okhttp3.Call?, e: IOException) {
                    println("failed")
                }

            })
        }
    }
```

movie response

```
class Movie2Response (val data: MutableList<Movie2>)
```

movie

```
class Movie2 (
    @SerializedName("id")
    var movieId: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("description")
    var synopsis: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("release_date")
    var release: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("poster")
    var poster: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("genre")
    var genre: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("title")
    var title: String? = null
```

)

and this is what i got from the json data

```
 V/body: {"data":[{"title":"Aquaman","description":""........
V/feed: [com.mqa.android.moviereview.model.Movie2@7509e04, com.mqa.android.moviereview.model.Movie2@890afed, com.mqa.android.moviereview.model.Movie2@9834e22, com.mqa.android.moviereview.model.Movie2@f02d0b3, com.mqa.android.moviereview.model.Movie2@d3b9670, com.mqa.android.moviereview.model.Movie2@4d55de9, com.mqa.android.moviereview.model.Movie2@cac2a6e, com.mqa.android.moviereview.model.Movie2@94fc50f, com.mqa.android.moviereview.model.Movie2@d9ba99c]
```

it shows right in body but in the array it show like that. please help what is wrong with it. because i want to show the title data to the spinner

Comment: Does the key in the json data are matched with the Movie2Response's class variables name ? If the key's in json data and variables name in the Model class is not matched you will not be able to parse it. You will get JsonParse exception. Also I request you to post your model class and the response json in the question so that we can help you better.

Comment: i've share it for u @RamMandal

Comment: Did you cross verified the Serialized Name string with the json data keys?

Comment: Code looks fine but once try this in below Log.v("feed", ""+movieFeed.data)
for(data in movieFeed.data){
Log.i("title","${data.title}")
}
and see the log it prints the title of movies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code worked pretty well as the log results showed. The real problem is the log function `Log.v("feed", ""+movieFeed.data)`. If you want to show pretty log, you should override the `toString()` method in `Movie2` class by:

> Open `Movie2` and right click in the `editor` -> `Generate` -> then click `toString()` to override it.

For data class in Kotlin, you can just add `data` before `class` keyword.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Everything okey with you data. You just forgot adding default realisation to log this object.

```
class Movie2(/*your fields*/)
```

just add **data** before class. will be something like that

```
data class Movie2(/*your fields*/)
```

Kotlin doesn't know ho toString you Movie2. If you wanna default realisation use [data class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html)

Comment: @QubaisyAndiyantama I edit my answer check it please