# How to separate some text of string from list?

Tags: android, string, kotlin

I tried to take a string from list but I want to separated that string become 2.
This is my list `[Aquaman (1), Bumblebee (3), Spiderman into the spider verse (4), Bohemian Rhapsody (7), A Star Is Born (8), Mary Poppins Returns (9), Captain Marvel (10), Ralph Breaks the Internet (11), Avengers: Endgame (12)]`

I want to separate the title and the number on it become 2 string but there are still one because I want to use the title for view and I want to use the number for id that I want to post. Can I do that? Please help.

This is my model

```
 class Movie2 (
        @SerializedName("id")
        var movieId: String? = null,
        @SerializedName("description")
        var synopsis: String? = null,
        @SerializedName("release_date")
        var release: String? = null,
        @SerializedName("poster")
        var poster: String? = null,
        @SerializedName("genre")
        var genre: String? = null,
        @SerializedName("title")
        var title: String? = null
) 
{
        override fun toString(): String {
                return "$title ($movieId)"
        }
}
```

this is where i have to put the data

```
override fun showMovieList(data: List<Movie2>) {
    movies = data[0]
    reviews.clear()
    reviews.addAll(data)
    data.forEach {
         title = it.title!!
        id = it.movieId!!
    }
    Log.v("id", "" + id)
    Log.v("title", "" + title)
    searchSpn.adapter = ArrayAdapter<Movie2>(this, R.layout.spinner_item, reviews)
    movie = searchSpn.selectedItem.toString()

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732790/android-split-stringthread - have a look at this

Comment: it can be but mine are list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val lData = listOf<String>()
lData.forEach {
  val data = it.split("(")
  val id = data[1].split(")")[0]
  val title = data[0]
}
```

its better you create class model like "Movie" with proprety uid and title
or you can keep in hashMap() like this

```
val lData = listOf<String>()
val lisofMovie = mutableListOf<HashMap<String, String>>()

lData.forEach {
  val data = it.split("(")

  val id = data[1].split(")")[0]
  val title = data[0]

  val lMovie = HashMap<String, String>()
  lMovie["id"] = id
  lMovie["title"] = title

  lisofMovie.add(lMovie)
}
```

Comment: actually i already make a model for it but it only can be print when i make it `toString` so i seprated it with `()` but don't have an idea to really seprated it into 2 string but still one

Comment: why you need toString() for print. why not just bring the model to list?

Comment: val data = it.split("(")
val id = data[1].split(")")[0]
val title = data[0]

Comment: because it don't want to print the right string like in my case here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54358667/how-to-parse-data-from-json?noredirect=1#comment95532314_54358667

Comment: you mean to show in listview or something so you use toString()

Comment: i think that i can use data.foreach to call it. but i have to make the data that can be put into ArrayAdapter

Comment: You can use 

movie = searchSpn.selectedItem as Movie2

movie is object from Movie2. Because you put Movie2 in adapter
just delete the toString()

Answer (score 0):

Its not quite clear what your issue is but you seem to want to use just the title in the spinner,  then one way to do this would be to override `toString` as you have done, but it sounds like you just want the title,  so I think it should be.

```
   override fun toString(): String {
            return title?:"no title provided"
    }
```

This does not change your underling list, or the objects in the list, so when you select an item you can get it via onItemSelected method, for example from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner#kotlin).

```
class SpinnerActivity : Activity(), AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, pos: Int, id: Long) {
        // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
        // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
    }

    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {
        // Another interface callback
   }
}
```

In your case you should get an instance of your Movie2 class, and then you can get the id my just calling `parent.movieId`